# Django DatabaseError "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" Editable related fields to object

Tags: database, django

I am trying to add inlines to my template but continue to get a Database error:

```
 more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I have 3 objects in my models.py that relate to each other. The user will be able to see which Teacher is selected and have all Owners under that Teacher listed (Teacher and Owner will only appear as an uneditable list). I'd like to have all the Pets under the Owner listed and editable. Any ideas on why I am receiving this error? And how I may be able to accomplish my goal?

**models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
        teacher = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Owner(models.Model):
       relevantteacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)     
       owner = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class PetName(models.Model):
        relevantowner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
        pet_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**forms.py**

```
class OwnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Owner

PetNameFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Owner,
    PetName,
    can_delete=False,
    extra=3,
    form=OwnerForm)
```

**views.py**

```
def petname(request, teacher_id):
   teacher = get_object_or_404(Teacher, pk=teacher_id)

   owners = Owner.objects.filter(relevantteacher=teacher_id)

   if request.method == "POST":
      petNameInlineFormSet = PetNameFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=owners)

      if petNameInlineFormSet.is_valid():
         petNameInlineFormSet.save()

         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))

   else:
      petNameInlineFormSet = PetNameFormSet(instance=owners) //error might be here?

   context = {'teacher': teacher, 'owners': owners, 'petNameInlineFormSet' : petNameInlineFormSet}
   return render(request, 'petname.html', context)
```

**Update:**

Here is the traceback:

```
File "hde/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.  response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/views.py" in petname
  60.  petNameInlineFormSet = PetNameFormSet(instance=owners)
File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  697.  queryset=qs, **kwargs)
File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  424.  super(BaseModelFormSet, self).__init__(**defaults)
```

Comment: Please specify the exact line number where the error happened.

Comment: I added a traceback. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: `PetNameFormSet(instance=owners)` I think problem is here as your are passing multiple owners but instance should be given as a single model object e.g. `instance=owner_obj`

Comment: You're right Aamir. I changed the instance to Teacher which will get rid of the error. However, since the instance doesn't relate to the Owner of the Pets, the Pet values are not being populated. The Pet inlines also do not relate back to the Owners. Any suggestions? Or should I throw up a new question?

Comment: You need to pass the owner object rather than teacher object as instance because your's `inlineformset_factory` consist of `Owner`.

Comment: yes, but passing the owner instance is what raised the database error in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34879/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-newtothis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to pass only 1 object to the instance

```
owner = owners[0]
```

then

```
instance=owner
```

However, I am only able to add/edit pet names 1 owner at a time. 
Thanks aamir for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is in the second line of the `views.py` file. I believe it is the call to the `get_object_or_404` method causing the error when you try to specify `teacher.id` in your template. The call to the `get_object_or_404` method is returning more than one row from the database, so calling `teacher.id` is not possible on it from more than one row.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly specify the primary key in model definition. Django automatically createS Auto Incremented field as a primary key if not supplied.

Comment: I was able to get this code to work if Teacher, Owner, Pet were uneditable lists. However, the minute Pet was put in as an inLine editable form, the database error was raised.